# Question about suprema/infima of partially ordered subsets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations, order-theory

This is another clarifying question; alas, I find myself confused once again by a seemingly innocuous statement in my lecture notes.

Let $S$ be a subset of a partially ordered set $(T, \preceq)$, and let $E$ be a subset of $S$, and let $\sup_{T}(E)$ denote the supremum of $E$ when $E$ is viewed as a subset of $T$, $\sup_{S}(E)$ when $E$ is viewed as a subset of $S$.  Now, I have written down here that "*For a subset $E \subseteq S$, the sets of upper and lower bounds will generally depend on whether one considers $E$ as a subset of $S$ or $T$*".  This all makes much sense to me.  However, I then have an exercise asking me to "*Show that, for $E \subseteq S$, one has $\sup_{T}(E) \preceq \sup_{S}(E)$ whenever both suprema exist*".  See, intuitively I would think that it has to be the other way around (that is, $\sup_{S}(E) \preceq \sup_{T}(E)$ whenever both suprema exist) simply because if $T \supseteq S$ then $\sup_{T}(E)$ has to "proceed" or "be at" $\sup_{S}(E)$ since either $\sup_{S}(E) \in T$ or $\sup_{S}(E)$ is somewhere "higher up" in the set of all upper bounds of $T$.  I mean, I can definitely see how $\sup_{T}(E)$ = $\sup_{S}(E)$, but **how could we ever have $\sup_{T}(E) \prec \sup_{S}(E)$?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Denote by $\def\ub{\mathop{\rm ub}\nolimits}\ub_S(E)$ the set of upper bounds of $E$ in $S$ (analogusly write $\ub_T(E)$). As obviously for $s\in \ub_S(E)$ we have $E \le s$ and $s \in T$, it follows that $\ub_S(E) \subseteq \ub_T(E)$. Now the suprema are the minima of the upper bounds, so 
$$ \sup_T(E) = \min \ub_T(E) \le \min \ub_S(E) = \sup_S(E) $$
Strict inequality can occur, if the supremum $\sup_T(E)$ is missing in $S$. For example, let $T = \omega + 2$, $S = T \setminus \{\omega\}$ and $E = \omega$. Then $\sup_T E = \omega$, but $\sup_S E = \omega + 1$.

Comment: Excellent, excellent...once more I have been shown the error of my ways by a very insightful and clearly communicating user here!  Your great answer made me realize that I was confusing $\sup_{T}(E)$ to be representing $T$ and not $E$ (as it is); I was conflating ub$_{T}(E)$ with $T$ itself and similarly with the analogues for $S$ with respect to $E$.  Thanks so much for the illumination.